# How to use 走勢 in finance/tech industry

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, traditional-characters

I'm struggling to clearly understand how to use the term 走勢. I've been told that this translates to "trend" but I'm not clear if this suggests trend in terms of general popularity, or trend in terms of market value. In what financial context can I use this term? For reference, I'm looking at this article and how it's being used: [影響比特幣走勢的幾大關鍵因素](https://www.etoro.com/zh-tw/blog/market-insights/%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF%E6%AF%94%E7%89%B9%E5%B9%A3%E8%B5%B0%E5%8B%A2%E7%9A%84%E5%B9%BE%E5%A4%A7%E9%97%9C%E9%8D%B5%E5%9B%A0%E7%B4%A0/) .

Comment: 走势 is probably closer to 'trajectory'.

Answer (score 1):

走勢 in this context means "(directional) trend" -

Example:

The **trend** of gold price is downward (a direction) -  黃金價格**走勢**向下

The **trend** of gold price is upward (a direction) - 黃金價格**走勢**向上

Similar word is "趨勢" trend; tendency

Example:

gold price is is **trending upward**  - 黃金價格呈**上升趨勢**

> *So sounds like the meaning is closer to "price/directional trend"?*

Not limited to price, It can apply to 銷量 too. E.g. "iPhone 在中國的銷量走勢向下" (iPhone sell in China is trending downward )

Comment: Ahh this makes more sense. So sounds like the meaning is closer to "price/directional trend"?